# Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class

Tags: java

I'm getting a weird error message in my java code...
I'm trying to make a simple calculator that can add two numbers together, but it is not working because I am new to Java... Here is the error code:

```
What would you like to addException in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 525
(([-+]?(((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))))|(((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))|(\Q-\E((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.LRUCache.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.integerPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at testing.Test1.main(Test1.java:9)
```

And my code is

```
package testing;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Test1 {
    public static Scanner scan;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1 = 0;
    System.out.print("What would you like to add");
    System.out.print(scan.nextInt(n1) + "You have selected" + scan.nextInt(n1));
    int n2 = 0;
    System.out.print(scan.nextInt(n2) + "You have selected" + scan.nextInt(n2));
    System.out.print("Calculation=" + n1+n2);
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out why it is not working and it is doing my head in -.-
I'm new to Java so if you could help me I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: When you pass `n1` and `n2` to the method `nextInt()` - what are you trying to do ? Are you sure that that's what it's doing ? Further, before you're calling `nextInt` or any `nextX` method - you should check if there is a next token in the scanner by calling `scan.hasNext()`

Comment: And what happens every time you call nextInt() on a scanner. Do you think that nextInt() returns the int it has read in the previous call to nextInt()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should try a different approach, something like this is more readable and, in my opinion, easier to work with if you are starting.

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan ;
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What would you like to add");
    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "You have selected" + n1);
    int n2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "You have selected" + n2);
    int calculation= n1+n2;
    System.out.println("Calculation=" + calculation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What would you like to add");
        int n1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have selected" + n1);

        int n2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have selected" + n2);

        System.out.println("Calculation=" + (n1 + n2));

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

1. nextInt() needs to be assigned to a variable (not passed to it)
2. n1 + n2 needs to be put in paranthesis (n1 + n2) or it will be processed as String.

Comment: What part of this code requires ENTER to be consumed? Sorry, that part of the answer makes me down-vote it.